# Why does the c++ clock return smaller values after sleeping?

Tags: c++, optimization, clock

I am trying to measure the performance of parts of my code in order to compare different statistical methods. I noticed that the measured cpu time is significantly lower if I let the thread sleep for some time beforehand. What is going on there? Am I using clock() wrong?

I am on an ubuntu system and using mpic++.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

#include <cmath>
#include <random>

#include <iostream>

#include <thread>

int main(){

//If I include this line then the measured time is 10 times smaller
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

std::default_random_engine generator;
std::normal_distribution<double> distribution = std::normal_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0);


int M= 100000;
double test = 0;

clock_t start = clock();
for(int counter=0;counter<M;counter++){
    test+=distribution(generator);
}
clock_t end = clock();

std::cout << "Generated "<<M<<" values in "<<((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<std::endl;
std::cout<<test;

return 0;
}
```

If I let the thread sleep then I get:
`Generated 100000 values in 0.01637`

Otherwise the result is:
`Generated 100000 values in 0.134786`

Strace results with `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));`:

```
    % time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.21    0.455606      455606         1           nanosleep
  0.51    0.002321          18       130           read
  0.06    0.000272          27        10           brk
  0.04    0.000203           1       241           mmap
  0.04    0.000176           2       101        11 openat
  0.03    0.000117           1       178           mprotect
  0.03    0.000115           1        90           close
  0.02    0.000112          19         6           sched_getaffinity
  0.02    0.000111           1        93           fstat
  0.02    0.000072           8         9           clone
  0.01    0.000053          27         2           prlimit64
  0.01    0.000039          20         2           clock_gettime
  0.01    0.000028          28         1           getpid
  0.01    0.000028           1        24         1 futex
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           write
  0.00    0.000000           0         8         8 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        15           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0        78        78 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           getdents
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrandom
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.459253                  1003        98 total
```

Result without `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));`:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 32.00    0.002080          16       130           read
 20.23    0.001315           5       241           mmap
 14.00    0.000910           5       178           mprotect
 10.15    0.000660           7       101        11 openat
  5.41    0.000352           5        78        78 access
  4.66    0.000303           3        93           fstat
  4.43    0.000288           3        90           close
  2.81    0.000183          20         9           clone
  1.82    0.000118          10        12         1 futex
  1.08    0.000070           5        15           munmap
  0.80    0.000052           5        10           brk
  0.62    0.000040           7         6           sched_getaffinity
  0.57    0.000037          19         2           write
  0.43    0.000028           4         8         8 stat
  0.38    0.000025          13         2           clock_gettime
  0.18    0.000012           3         4           getdents
  0.15    0.000010           5         2           prlimit64
  0.14    0.000009           9         1           getpid
  0.03    0.000002           1         2           rt_sigaction
  0.03    0.000002           2         1           arch_prctl
  0.03    0.000002           2         1           getrandom
  0.02    0.000001           1         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.02    0.000001           1         1           set_tid_address
  0.02    0.000001           1         1           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.006501                   990        98 total
```

Comment: You should use chrono to measure the time instead of clock. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now/

Comment: It might be interesting to look at `strace` output with timing details for the two programs. The tracing will probably change the times, but there still might be some noticeable differences giving hints.

Comment: I think chrono would not help me. My program is multi threaded and chrono at least to my knowledge measures the real time and not cpu time.

Comment: I have never worked with strace, I have added the results that I got. To me it does not look very different. Is it normal that nanosleep is less than half the input?

Comment: @user509065: "*My program is multi threaded and chrono at least to my knowledge measures the real time and not cpu time*" That depends entirely on which clock from `chrono` you use.

Comment: @NicolBolas which clock in std::chrono measures CPU time?

Comment: @n.m.: "CPU time" is not a thing defined by the standard, so you'll have to be more specific about the exact properties you want out of the clock. `steady_clock` is a clock that cannot go backwards, and `high_resolution_clock` is a clock that has the highest resolution available.

Comment: Doesn't this line result in sleep? ````std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));````

Comment: clock() measures CPU time used by the program.  Of course it is less when you sleep.

Comment: @NicolBolas All std::chrono clocks are *wall clocks*. They measure *elapsed time*. The `clock` function is not a wall clock. It measures, drumroll, an actual quote from the C standard, "processor time used by the program".

Comment: @stark this makes zero sense. The amount of work done by the program  does not change when you *add* a sleep.

Comment: Sorry if I am confusing, I just picked up programming in C++ again after 6 years of only working in python and matlab. The clock should only count time spent by the cpu on this task and not stuff in the background. Additionally it should also support multiple threads insofar that if 2 my program uses 2 cores the time should run twice as fast. Hopefully that makes sense and I am not confusing something.

Comment: "My program is multi threaded" This is not in the posted code. Are you sure ppsted code is a [mcve]? I cannot reproduce your results, the time reported stays the same with and without sleep. What compilation command are you using?

Comment: @n.m.: "*All std::chrono clocks are wall clocks. They measure elapsed time.*" I don't know what you mean by "elapsed time" and how that differs from "processor time". They're all just some count relative to a value, right? Even if a particular thread goes to sleep, the CPU still keeps processing. So it's not like "processor time" represents a measurement of the cycle count that was actually processed by a thread.

Comment: @NicolBolas These terms are pretty standard, you may want to look them up. You may also want to check how major implementations interpret them. Note, on Windows, `clock` is not standard, this is mentioned in Microsoft documentation, you want to read it too. "Even if a particular thread goes to sleep, the CPU still keeps processing" It may or may not be processing (some processors halt). If it processes, it processes something other than your program. Your program is not using a processor while it sleeps.

Comment: You may be experiencing a CPU power saving artifact. When CPU load is low, your system automatically lowers CPU frequency to save power and cool the chip. When load is high, the frequency is dialed back up. You may want to disable this feature for performance measurements. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021748/set-cpu-governor-to-performance-in-18-04

Comment: You might have a look at `times` which is similar to `clock` in that it only counts process time, but specifically counts child process time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. I am working in eclipse and had a header with corresponding cpp file still in the same project. TIL that eclipse links files even if I do not include them. This file contains a class with a variable of type dealii::FullMatrix:

```
//Coefficients.h

#ifndef COEFFICIENTS_H_
#define COEFFICIENTS_H_
#include <deal.II/lac/full_matrix.h>

class Coefficients{
public:
    Coefficients(int dim);
protected:
    dealii::FullMatrix<double> values;
};

#endif /* COEFFICIENTS_H_ */
```

In the cpp file the constructor initializes the matrix:

```
//Coefficients.cpp

#include "Coefficients.h"

Coefficients::Coefficients(int dim):values(dim,dim){};
```

This somehow resulted in the time difference. For now I just put the constructor in my header file and that seems to solve the issue. I would be very interested if any of you know whats going on there.

Thank you for the discussion and all the interesting answers. A special thanks to n.m. for testing my program.